# wire sub panel about 30 feet from main panel 50amp

Tags: electrical

Can I use #8 copper with a 50amp breaker to wire my sub panel using 3/4" electrical PVC pipe running two leads one neural one ground. I have a 125amp sub panel this is for a new addition with full cellar one bed room one bath

Comment: I'm not completely sure what you're describing by "...running two leads one neural (sic) one ground." Presuming you're covered by the U.S. electrical code (or a virtually identical one like Canada), you need 4 conductors for your subpanel. That's two (2) hot leads, one (1) grounded ("neutral") lead and one grounding conductor.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds about right, as long as the new panel isn't too far from the original panel. You'll need 4 conductors, two ungrounded (hot), one grounded (neutral), and one grounding.